# SEO for each page thats added dynamically : react js

Tags: reactjs, seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I am trying to create a site like stackoverflow where there can be multiple questions added by users and they can answer
https://wixten.com/

But I don't know how to seo for each page that's added dynamically when a question is asked.

I have configured the dynamic page that is created when each page is created with helmet so each route has its own page title and description.

Since all inner pages are dynamically generated, I am not able to create site maps for each pages.

Since Google bot does not crawl through the dynamic urls I have no idea how I can index these pages - I need help.

Hope someone will help me I have been stuck with this for the past 2 weeks, I tried everything on the internet I could find but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Adding **links** pointing to the dynamic pages is the key. For example if you have a list of questions like in stackoverflow, google has already accessed that page (list of questions) and it's a matter of time for your new page to get indexed. The other thing you have to do is create a **dynamic sitemap.xml** file witch changes depending on the creating/deletion of pages in your website :)

Comment: can u sugest any method to create a dymanic sitemap.xml that updates sitemap.xml on creation and deletion of new pages

Comment: This needs to happen in the backend. I suggest researching how to generate a file in the language your using in the backend.

Comment: i am using express.js in heroku can u sugest any method

Comment: I think this will do the trick: [Express - write to file](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/express+js+write+to+file). Just change the file extension and fill it with the correct content.

Comment: i tryed as u asked and created my sitemap.txt file in my express.js  but iam not able to connect it to google serach console  i have my  express.js  hosted in  heroku how can i connet google search console to it

Comment: my domain is https://wixten.com  i have hosted react js in firebase   i have connected google search console using this domain  , my express which is on herku runs on this domian https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Can you access the sitemap file on wixten.com/sitemap.xml? If the answer is yes you can point that exact url in the Google Search Console. Or else you have to find why the file isn't accessible on that url. Do some more research so you can setup everything correctly.